# Struts2 page navigation for add and edit actions

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I need to understand simple flow as I'm new to Struts2 and struggling with it.

I have simple form for adding student info. This form is used to Add & Edit with add & edit actions respectively and both calling one method called saveOrUpdate which has to check id and insert or update the user. Something common. URLs I use are below

```
http://localhost:8080/Student/add  -> action = add  -> method = saveOrUpdate -> register.jsp
http://localhost:8080/Student/edit -> action = edit -> method = saveOrUpdate -> register.jsp
```

**My Problem:**

When I type `http://localhost:8080/Student/add` than register.jsp is displayed but at the same time saveOrUpdate is triggered thus executing code inside it (insert condition).

How do I show user blank new register.jsp page on `http://localhost:8080/Student/add` without executing saveOrUpdate?

***My solution is below but how do you do this. Is my approach right?. It was different before but reading online tutorials concluded below***. This is little verbose as add & edit use same result. Any help.

```
<action name="add">
            <result>/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="edit">
            <result>/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

**register.jsp button will have action below for add & edit data.**

```
<action name="insertOrUpdateStudent" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction" method="insertOrUpdateStudent">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">list</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use global-results like this:

```
<package>
   <global-results>
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
   </global-results>

   <action name="add"/>
   <action name="edit"/>
</package>
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one problem. For Add you have to display the view only but in Edit you have to retrieve record to display in view. What I think is to Add & Edit(reterieve record) action used to display the view and than insertOrUpdate action/method to handle Add/Update data. That's what I think.

Comment: Pass an id attribute as url parameter to edit action and retrieve the data you need, using Preparable interface or define other method `<action name="edit" method="edit"/>` or REST style `<action name="edit/*"><param name="id" value="{1}/></action>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add different methods for your add/edit actions.

```
<action name="add" method="add" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction">
  <result>/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="edit" method="edit" class="com.myapp.actions.StudentAction">
  <result>/WEB-INF/pages/student/register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

Add conventions plugin: struts2-conventions-plugin-x.x.x.jar, where x.x.x is version.

Create:
/WEB-INF/content/register-input.jsp and
/WEB-INF/content/register-success.jsp

If the Register class returns input, register-input will be called, if it returns success register-success will be called. If you call register-input directly and there is no RegisterInput class and so the view is rendered directly.

It might be hard to see the value at first but try it and you'll be hooked.

To put it more in like with your naming you could return -add, -edit, etc with appropriate views although personally I would not do this and stick with the built in strings (success, input, error, ...) and map the add, edit etc into the namespace.